# Does the data type used in JPA entity class for defining a column impact the creation of a query in DAO?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

In java entity class, I defined a named query and data types for columns. I executed the query in a DAO class but got the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [TestEntity] is incompatible with query return type [class java.util.Date]`. I have not used a java.util.Date class for defining the mydate column, instead I used java.sql.Timestamp, so it's unclear why the error is referring to java.util.Date. It looks like I have done something wrong, but it's unclear what it is.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
@NamedQuery(name = "findByTestId", query = "select u.mydate from TestEntity u where u.my_id = :testId")

public class TestEntity {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_ID")
    private String my_id;

    @Column(name = "mydate")
    private java.sql.Timestamp mydate;
```

In  DAO class

```
public classTest Dao extends BaseDao

  public List<TestEntity> findByTestId(String id) {
            return execute("punit", entityManager -> {
                TypedQuery<TestEntity> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByTestId", TestEntity.class);
                query.setParameter("testId", id);
                return query.getResultList();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Your usage of the named query is weird. You select only the date field, but in your snippet in the DAO you are returning the TestEntity. The ORM will not now how to map the column mydate to the type TestEntity. The cast exception is probable caused because java.sql.Timestamp enherits from java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with below code, it will work.

```
   @Column(name = "mydate")
    private Date mydate;
```

The query return type need be compatible with the entity object in which you want to cast it. Update your code

```
TypedQuery<Date>date= entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByTestId", Date.class);
```

And return type of this method should be like **`List<Date>`**.
This will help you.

Comment: How would this solve the issue? The ORM mapper is being asked to return a TestEntity when selecting a java.sql.Timestamp in the named query.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius `The query return type need be compatible with the entity object in which you want to cast it.` I had updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code. you should change the query to this

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findByTestId", query = "select u from TestEntity u where u.my_id = :testId")
```

if you want to get only the date you have to edit your method.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is supposed to return a list of java.util.Timestamp objects since you have included only "mydate" field in the select list, but in the creation of the typed query in findByTestId method you are instructing JPA to return a List of TestEntity objects. The easiest way to fix this is to alter your query like this:

```
"select u from TestEntity u where u.my_id = :testId"
```

In addition, java.sql.Timestamp is a subclass of java.util.Date, which may explain why the error refers to java.util.Date.